# Sharepoint: How do I move stuff between sites

Tags: sharepoint

What is the best way to move lists and wiki pages from one SharePoint server to another?

Answer (score 1):

If preserving item-level permissions is not too important, you can just create a list template from the list, export that template, and then import it on the new server.